# Correctly calculate 24 hr format duration difference

Tags: php, variables, time, difference

I am trying to calculate the total hours in a 24 hour start time and end time:

```
var a = 10 - 01;
var b = 8 - 23;
var c = 17 - 08;
var result_a = a + " Hours";
var result_b = b + " Hours";
var result_c = c + " Hours";
console.log(result_a); 
console.log(result_b); 
console.log(result_c);
```

so the calcuation is for instance in `var a` end time (10:00) - start time (01:00) I get 9 hours. This is the same with `var c`

My problem is if I set the start time to 23:00 and the end time to 08:00 (11:00pm - 8:00am), I get -15 because it will be 8 - 23.

`var b` should also be "9 Hours". What should be the correct formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to verify whether start is greater than end, because both possibilities make sense yet require different calculations:

```
08:00 to 23:00 -> 15h (end - start)
23:00 to 08:00 ->  9h (end - start + 24)
```

It's worth noting that this will not take daylight saving time into account. For that, you need specific dates. If you have such information, you can simply resort to native date calculations, namely [`DateTime::diff()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php).

Comment: Just what I needed thank you. I am only calculating hours so this specific section of what I am doing probably cannot use `DateTime:diff()`. I should add an if to add by 24 if the result is negative to get the correct duration, thanks again!.

Comment: Don't forget the edge case where both are equal. Ask yourself if `23:00 to 23:00` needs to be `0` or`24`.